# How to iterate this kind of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I access the int value in a list that looks like this?

```
occurence_list = [["sleep", ["morning_meds", 2], ["watching_tv", 3]], ["morning_meds", ["sleep", 1], ["watching_tv", 3]]]
```

Comment: What is the output you are looking for?

Comment: it looks like each sublist has a first element that is a string and the other two elements are lists where the second element is the desired int. So you can do `occurence_list[0][1][1]  -> 2`,    `occurence_list[0][2][1]  -> 3` ,   `occurence_list[1][1][1]  -> 1`,     `occurence_list[1][2][1]  -> 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much to go on based on your example. You would need to know the structure of the array to make a more informed decision. However, if you want to generalise the issue, saying that you have an arbirarily nested array, and you want to extract all integers, you could do this:

```py
def get_ints(nested_list):
    for item in nested_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from get_ints(item)
        if isinstance(item, int):
            yield item

ints = list(get_ints(occurence_list))
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Perfect use of *recursive generator* here.  Elegant and clear. +1  (suggest to use *lol* instead of ```l``` as the *list of list*)

Comment: Thank you @DanielHao `lol` may not be the best name either, not sure if it would correctly indicate the level of nesting. Renamed it to `nested_list`.

Comment: It is a bit more complex as in your code if you want to cover next level of generalizing because along with lists there are tuples, sets, dictionaries and other iterable objects which can contain an integer. At that level you have to use then `try: except`. But ... I suppose that at the level the question was asked, the problem was to know how to reach deeper elements in nested lists.

Comment: @Claudio ah. good point. But you don't need a `try` for that. You can just use the `Iterable` collection base class. Added it to my answer.

Comment: @tituszban To my knowledge not every object you can iterate over is an instance of Iterable. This is the reason for `try`. And sorry ... don't just have links at hand which deal with this kind of Python problems. Haven't digged into it deep enough yet, so maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list expands the same way as listed:

```py
occurence_list = [["sleep", ["morning_meds", 2], ["watching_tv", 3]], ["morning_meds", ["sleep", 1], ["watching_tv", 3]]] 
for i in occurence_list:
    # On second and third there is a int.
    action = i[1][1]
    second_action = i[2][1]
    print(action,second_action) # 2 3 \n 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would print different aspect of this list:

```py
occurence_list = [["sleep", ["morning_meds", 2], ["watching_tv", 3]], ["morning_meds", ["sleep", 1], ["watching_tv", 3]]] 
print[0][1]
>> ['morning_meds', 2]
print[0][1][1]
>> 2
```

Comment: The poster did ask about how to iterate the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a listing of the int values one of unlimited number of options doing this will be:

```
occurrence_list = [["sleep", ["morning_meds", 2], ["watching_tv", 3]], ["morning_meds", ["sleep", 1], ["watching_tv", 3]]] 
index_of_int = 1
for occurrence in occurrence_list:
    txt, list_1, list_2 = occurrence
    print(list_1[index_of_int], list_2[index_of_int])
# prints: 
#         2 3
#         1 3
```

To get a better overview of the nested list structure as with `print` you can use `pprint` with 4 spaces indentation:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(occurrence_list, indent=4)
pprint_output = """
[   ['sleep', ['morning_meds', 2], ['watching_tv', 3]],
    ['morning_meds', ['sleep', 1], ['watching_tv', 3]]] 
"""
```

or use the not in Python distribution included pandas module:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(occurrence_list)
print(df)
pandas_df_print = """
              0                  1                 2
0         sleep  [morning_meds, 2]  [watching_tv, 3]
1  morning_meds         [sleep, 1]  [watching_tv, 3]
"""
```

From the nested list overview you can see how deep you need to nest indices to obtain a single value from a nested list. Each list within list element require further index. This is how it comes that to get the `1` in `['sleep', 1]` you need three indices: `occurrence_list[1][1][1]`. The first two indices of an integer value you can take from the pandas dataframe print output (first index is the index of the row, second of the column) with printed indices for rows and columns.

You  can check in code if your guess about the right indexing was OK with:

```
assert occurrence_list[1][1][1] == 1
```

which will give an assertion error if the indices don't lead to the given specified value.

If you want to extract all integer values from a nested list you will find the code for it in the answer posted by *tituszban*.